# ASIHttpRequest throws an error and I just can't figure out why

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I've been following the examples given at:  http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/76730-webservice-how.html in order to try and get my iphone app to connect to a webservice.  However, when I use the following code, it throws me an error:

```
-(IBAction) startSend:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mywebsitehere"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithString:@""];
    xmlString=AS(xmlString,@"<id>");
    xmlString=AS(xmlString,@"the id would go here.");
    xmlString=AS(xmlString,@"</id>");
    xmlString=AS(xmlString,@"<Data>");
    xmlString=AS(xmlString,@"Binary Data would be read here.");
    xmlString=AS(xmlString, @"</Data>");
    NSData* xmlData=[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request appendPostData:xmlData];

    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestCompleted:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestError:)];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestCompleted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"%d", responseString);
}


- (void)requestError:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"error description : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

When I run this, I'll get the error message of:  error description : Unable to start HTTP connection.

What would cause it to be unable to start an HTTP connection?

Comment: This error is usually caused by there being a problem (typo, bad string formatting) with the URL you are trying to connect to. Have you made sure that when you `NSLog([request.url absoluteString])` that it returns the value you expect?

Comment: hey...did you solve this question??
share the answer please :)

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the address of the error object instead of the object itself.  Use this instead:

```
NSLog(@"The error is: %@", error);
```

The same goes for the responseString:

```
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Are you sure it is c# ?

Second, you could try

```
NSLog(@"error description : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

It would be more comprehensive

Comment: Oh wow, I don't even know how I marked it as C#?  Is there a way for me to remove the tag?  Also, the error it returns is:  error description : Unable to start HTTP connection

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it hasn't been marked as complete yet.  I wrestled with this for a while, and it turned out I had dome something like this:

`NSString *webserviceBase=@"http://some/url";
NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[webserviceBase stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cmd"]];`

Note that `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` mangles the `http://` portion of the URL. So, if you're doing something similar, make sure the base includes a trailing slash, and use `stringByAppendingString:` instead.